# Insertion sort: Why we decrease j by one?

Tags: java, insertion-sort

Why we decrease j by one (j--)? What does it do actually?

```
void sort(int arr[])
{
    int n = arr.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        int key = arr[i];
        int j = i - 1;

        while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > key) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j + 1] = key;
    }
}
```

Comment: you search from `i-1` to `0`, so in decrease way, j should go down so

Comment: As opposed to what? If you didn't decrease `j` it would be an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider an array of 12,45,51,23,19,8.
Note that the sub-array 12,45,51 is already sorted.
23 should be placed next to 12.
To place 23 next to 12 we need to move the positions of 45 and 51

```
// In Case of i=3 
key=23
j=2
```

Goes to inside `while` loop fist time at the end the

```
array=12,45,51,51,19,8
key=23
j=1
```

Second time goes in inside the `while` loop at the end

```
array=12,45,45,51,19,8
key=23
j=0
```

and ends the `while` loop.

```
arr[j + 1] = key; //this statement gets executed
```

After that the array =12,23,45,51,19,8.
Hence `j--` statement helps in changing the position of elements in the array.